# Finding more constructible solutions to polynomial equations

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, galois-theory, geometric-construction

**Summary:** I have two polynomial equations in four variables. How can I find solutions using [constructible numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number)? Can I use the fact that I know one (or a few closely related) such solutions to find more beyond these?

In [my answer on constructing “double” circumscribed pentagons](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4828932/35416) I characterized solutions to a geometric problem by two polynomial equations:

\begin{align*}
0 &= a^2b^2c - a^2b^2d + a^2bd^2 - a^2cd^2 + ac^2d^2 - bc^2d^2 \\&\quad - a^2b - 4abc - b^2c - ac^2 + bc^2 + a^2d + b^2d + 4bcd - ad^2 + cd^2 + a - d
\\
0 &= a^2bc + ab^2c - ab^2d - a^2cd + ac^2d - bc^2d + abd^2 - bcd^2 - ab - ac + bd + cd
\end{align*}

Or, if you want to copy and paste them:

```
0 = a^2*b^2*c - a^2*b^2*d + a^2*b*d^2 - a^2*c*d^2 + a*c^2*d^2 - b*c^2*d^2 - a^2*b - 4*a*b*c - b^2*c - a*c^2 + b*c^2 + a^2*d + b^2*d + 4*b*c*d - a*d^2 + c*d^2 + a - d
0 = a^2*b*c + a*b^2*c - a*b^2*d - a^2*c*d + a*c^2*d - b*c^2*d + a*b*d^2 - b*c*d^2 - a*b - a*c + b*d + c*d
```

Four different permutations of the roots of $5x^4 - 10x^2 + 1$ solve these equations, e.g.

$$
a = -\sqrt{1+\frac2{\sqrt5}}\qquad
b = -\sqrt{1-\frac2{\sqrt5}}\qquad
c = \sqrt{1-\frac2{\sqrt5}}\qquad
d = \sqrt{1+\frac2{\sqrt5}}
$$

This solution corresponds to a geometric arrangement with a regular pentagon. But the question statement I was trying to answer was explicitly looking for a non-regular solution, so this specific solution is not acceptable. At the same time the original question was asking for a construction, so only a solution using constructible numbers would have a chance to satisfy that aspect.

In [my original answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4828932/35416) I drew a picture using

\begin{align*}
a &= -1.2 & 5a+6 &= 0 \\
b &\approx -0.183 &
18032b^4 + 81385b^3 - 68156b^2 - 21040b - 1088 &= 0\\
c &= \phantom+0.5 & 2c-1 &= 0 \\
d &\approx \phantom+1.490 &
78608d^4 + 167620d^3 - 575824d^2 - 21430d + 368293 &= 0
\end{align*}

But the [Galois group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_group) of those polynomials for $b$ and $d$ is the $S_4$ with order $4!=24$. Since that order is not a power of two, these algebraic numbers are proven not to be constructible. I could not provide a constructible answer, much less an actual construction.

**Core question:** How can I find a solution where all four variables are distinct constructible numbers, and at least one of them is not a root of $5x^4 - 10x^2 + 1$?

Ideally I would find some parametrization, where I can pick one rational number arbitrarily and derive all four variables from that. But even finding a single different solution should help understand this problem better.

Given how surprisingly hard some similar-looking problems around [diophantine equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation) turn out to be, I wouldn't be surprised at all if this is a fairly hard problem. So I'm also prepared to accept answers providing evidence showing this to indeed be a hard problem. Maybe by showing the existence question to be a reasonably generic instance of a known NP-hard problem, or pointers at literature discussing similar problems.

I know usually I should show my own work for tackling the problem, but I don't have the first idea where to start. I attempted to isolate some additional relationships between the known regular pentagon arrangement, and combine that with the given equations using resultants. But the responses I got tended to either force the regular pentagon arrangement, or quickly lead to some numbers being equal to one another. I can't think of any systematic approach, just this hit and miss guesswork.

One thing that I did find out is that if I use an affine combination of the four permutations of the regular solution, they will all satisfy the second equation. But not the first, and I haven't found a way to leverage this observation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Part 1.**

Given your two equations, eliminating $d$ between them using resultants yields the quartic in $b$ in your [other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4828130/constructing-double-circumscribed-pentagons),

$$
(-a^4c^2 - a^3c^3 + a^2c^4 - a^3c - 5a^2c^2 + 3ac^3 - 5ac + 2c^2 - 1)\,b^4 \\
+ (a^4c^3 - 2a^3c^4 + a^4c + 2a^3c^2 - 4a^2c^3 - 3ac^4 + c^5 + 8a^2c - 12ac^2 + c^3 + 3a - 4c)\,b^3 \\
+ (a^4c^4 - a^4c^2 + 7a^2c^4 - 3ac^5 - 4a^3c + 4a^2c^2 + 6ac^3 - 3c^4 - 3a^2 + 5ac - c^2)\,b^2 \\
+ (a^4c^3 - 5a^3c^4 + 3a^2c^5 + a^4c - 10a^2c^3 + 6ac^4 + a^3 - a^2c - 6ac^2 + 3c^3 - c)\,b \\
+ (a^4c^4 - a^3c^5 + 3a^3c^3 - 3a^2c^4 + 3a^2c^2 - 3ac^3 + ac - c^2) = 0
$$

To avoid cube roots, one way to do it is to find $(a,c)$ such that this quartic factors into two *quadratics*. I don't know your positivity requirements for $(a,c)$, but if sign is not an issue, then two such values are:

**I.** $(a,c) = (1/2,\,1)\,$ yielding $(b,d)$ as the appropriate roots of,

$$
3 + 6 b + b^2 = 0\\
1 - 6 d + 3 d^2 = 0$$

**II.** $(a,c) = (1/2,\,3)\,$ yielding $(b,d)$ as the appropriate roots of,

$$
-5 + 2 b + b^2 = 0\\ 
-1 + 2 d + 5 d^2 = 0 $$

since your $d$ from the other post is also just a quadratic. These particular $(a,b,c,d)$ should be constructible.

---

**Part 2.** (*Added a day later*)

We can prove that there are in fact **infinitely** many constructible $(a,b,c,d)$ such that $a<b<c<d.\,$ The OP's aforementioned system of two equations is,

\begin{align*}
0 &= a^2b^2c - a^2b^2d + a^2bd^2 - a^2cd^2 + ac^2d^2 - bc^2d^2 \\&\quad - a^2b - 4abc - b^2c - ac^2 + bc^2 + a^2d + b^2d + 4bcd - ad^2 + cd^2 + a - d
\\
0 &= a^2bc + ab^2c - ab^2d - a^2cd + ac^2d - bc^2d + abd^2 - bcd^2 - ab - ac + bd + cd
\end{align*}

A solution to this was known as permutations of the roots of $5x^4 - 10x^2 + 1=0$, namely,

$$(a,b,c,d) \approx (-1.376381,\; -0.324919,\; 0.324919,\; 1.376381)$$

Note that $c= -b,\;d=-a$. Employing this same relationship satisfies the second equation and the first becomes the simpler,

$$a - a^3 - a^2 b + a^4 b + 3 a b^2 + a^3 b^2 + b^3 - a^2 b^3= 0$$

Using the substitution $a=x,\,b=nx,$ it transforms into the constructible quartic,

$$(n + n^2 - n^3)x^4 - (1 + n - 3n^2 - n^3)x^2 + 1 = 0$$

If $0<n<0.25$ and appropriate root $x$ chosen, then $a<b<c<d.$ For example, let $n=1/5=0.20$ and $x = -\sqrt{\frac{67+12\sqrt6}{29}} \approx -1.823163$ then,

$$(a,b,c,d) \approx (-1.823163,\; -0.364633,\; 0.364633,\; 1.823163)$$

where $n=b/a = 0.20,$ and so on for infinitely many $n$.

**P.S.** Note that the OP's original answer has $n=b/a = 1/\phi^3 \approx 0.23$ (with golden ratio $\phi$) so falls within the same range of $0<n<0.25$.

Comment: Can you explain in some more detail how you found the parameters that allowed factoring the quartic? Was that trial and error, or is there some form of discriminant that would allow for a targeted search?

Comment: @MvG At first I checked the discriminant of your quartic to check if it can be made a square, but it is a polynomial of degree $> 4$ so can't be treated as an elliptic curve. So I just used trial and error. Do you have positivity requirements, or do these two values will do for now?

Comment: My question as stated doesn't have any positivity requirements. In order to get a nice picture I would prefer $a<b<c<d$ or $a>b>c>d$, but I decided not to make that a requirement of the question and instead see whether I can adapt answers to yield something pleasing.